# Cómo posicionar una ventana emergente php

Tags: type

Estoy utilizando un input type=color y la ventana se abre siempre en la esquina superior izquierda.
No se si es posible, pero me gustaría cambiarla de posición y no veo cómo.
He probado varias cosas pero nada funciona.
Muchas gracias de antemano

No hay mucho código que mostrar es un archivo .php y dentro de un div está

```html
echo '<h3>Selecciona el color de fondo: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
echo '<input type="color" name="colorfondo"  value="#ffffff"></h3>';
```

al hacer click, aparece el cuadro con la paleta de colores.

Comment: Has probado con css? Si puedes añadir algo de código sobre lo que estas haciendo seria de bastante ayuda para nosotros

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677423/how-to-position-a-color-picker-opened-through-html5s-color-input Basicamente viene a decir que el uso de esa modal viene especificado por el navegador, no se puede modificar su posicionamiento.